# TSQL - calculate AVG for currency rates over complete year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, average

I have a table with ECB exchange rates for which I want to calculate the average rate for each year.

Let me explain with this image:

[image]

As you can see the AVGRate in this example takes the AVG for each Currency over the existing year.
The output should then only show one AVG for each Currency, giving me four rows in this case.

So the final output version should give me the ECBDate (with records like "BRL-2013-01-02"), the AVGRate and the Year column.

Of course this should also work for 2014 and so on.

see my [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ee56/6) for what I got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @Original TABLE
(
    [Date] DATE, 
    Currency VARCHAR(3), 
    Rate NUMERIC(9,4)
)

INSERT INTO @Original ([Date], Currency, Rate)
VALUES
    ('2013-01-02', 'BRL', 2.707),
    ('2013-01-03', 'BRL', 2.6828),
    ('2013-01-02', 'CNY', 8.1703),
    ('2013-01-03', 'CNY', 8.4014),
    ('2013-01-02', 'CZK', 25.218),
    ('2013-01-03', 'CZK', 25.26),
    ('2013-01-02', 'USD', 1.3262),
    ('2013-01-03', 'USD', 1.3102)

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
          *
        , [Year] = YEAR(o.[Date])
        , id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(o.[Date]), Currency ORDER BY Currency) 
    FROM @Original o
    WHERE o.[Date] BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
)
SELECT 
      ECB_Date = t.Currency  + '-' + CAST(t.[Date] AS CHAR(10))
    , ECB_Rate = t.Rate
    , t.[Year]
    , t2.AVG_ECBRate
FROM cte t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
          o.Currency
        , o.[Year]
        , id = MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY o.[Year], o.Currency) 
        , AVG_ECBRate = AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,4), o.Rate)) OVER (PARTITION BY o.[Year], o.Currency)
    FROM cte o
) t2 ON t.Currency = t2.Currency AND t.[Year] = t2.[Year] AND t.id = t2.id
```

**Output:**

```
ECB_Date       ECB_Rate   Year        AVG_ECBRate
-------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
BRL-2013-01-02 2.7070     2013         
BRL-2013-01-03 2.6828     2013        2.694900
CNY-2013-01-02 8.1703     2013         
CNY-2013-01-03 8.4014     2013        8.285850
CZK-2013-01-02 25.2180    2013         
CZK-2013-01-03 25.2600    2013        25.239000
USD-2013-01-02 1.3262     2013         
USD-2013-01-03 1.3102     2013        1.318200
```

Comment: I glad to help you. To be honest, for a long while I could not understand where the error was. I can suggest you our free online SQL formatting service [Online SQL Format](http://www.sql-format.com/).